# Retrieve image routes in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to retrieve an image from gallery using the [image_picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker#-example-tab-) package and then store the images route in a database. After that I would like to retrieve the route from db and show the image.

Tn short, this is what my code so far does:

```
  File _image;

  Future getGalleryImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }
```

The method above gets the image from the users gallery, and then

```
        new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo), onPressed: (){
          getGalleryImage();
        }),
        new Container(
          child: _image == null
              ? new Container()
              : new Image.file(_image),
        ),
```

displays the image.

I would now like to know 1) how to retrieve a string with the route to the selected image and 2) how to display the image based on the route string. Any help would be highly appreciated since I am kind of stuck on this issue.

Comment: What is " route to the selected image"?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer What I mean by that is the file path (e.g. /usr/lib/photo.jpg). I would like to get the file path (preferably as a string) of the photo selected by the user, then store it in a database and after that query the value from db and use it to display said image.

Comment: What `usr/lib` directory are you referring to?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer `/usr/lib/photo.jpg` was just an example, that is why I used e.g. I was mainly looking to retrieve the file path of the selected photo, do you know whether this is possible with the code I mentioned in the original question?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why do you think the file is at the location that is stored in the database?

Comment: I probably phrased my question poorly, so here is a short explanation of what I would like to do: The `image_picker` plugin opens the gallery and allows the user to choose a photo. Then the plugin returns the chosen image in the `File` format, which unfortunately cannot be stored in the db I use. That is why I would like to know how to get the file path to the chosen photo instead of the actual image file, so that I can store only the file path to the image as a `String` in the database and then use the file path to display the image in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImagePicker` returns a `File` and you get the path using the `File`s `path` getter.

```
final file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
print(file.path);
```

You can then later create a new `File` instance with the retrieved path

```
final file = File(path);
```

and display it using for example

```
Image.file(file);
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks a lot for your answer!